# How to uncomment block java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using shortcut ctrl+shift+/ and i get this:

```
/*  public void printObjects() {
        for (T o : array) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }*/
```

and after **save** (for example ctrl +s ), my work gets this :

```
/*
     * public void printObjects() { for (T o : array) { System.out.println(o); }
     * }
     */
```

and of course ctrl + +shift + \ doesn't work. And i left with annoying "stars".

Eclipse Mars 4.5

Comment: I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. It toggles line comment (`//`). Not as pretty, but easier to toggle back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> instead, when having marked the text you want to be turned into a comment. Works both to comment and uncomment and is way more flexible, because you can easily comment/uncomment single lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL + SHIFT + C

but then every single line is commented out with //

I think you also can resolve your problem by apdapting the saving options of your eclipse instance.